# C# LINQ : Dynamically create property and values that includes sum of a value from a grouped query

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, select, sum

My Title is slightly confusing so I will explain it here.

This is my sample query and what I wish to achieve:

```
var results = from row in toSearch.AsEnumerable()
              group by row.Field<String>("Somename") into grp
              select new
                        {
                         GroupMe = grp.Key,

                         foreach (var k in someDic.Keys){
                               TODOPROPERTYNAMEFROMk = grp.sum(x => grp.k);
                         }
                          };
```

This is the general idea of what I want to achieve. Based on a dictionary of keys, I want to create property names from it while summing up the data from the grouped query. The sum will be based off the value of the keys. 
toSearch is a datatable and all of the keys of the dictionary makes up some of the headers of the datatable. This to me seems impossible and I have searched up a few sources and one of it (I lost the author sorry....) gave me this solution:

```
//For generating dynamic objects fr
  public static object DynamicProjection(object input, IEnumerable<string> properties)
{
    var type = input.GetType();
    dynamic dObject = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
    var dDict = dObject as IDictionary<string, object>;

    foreach (var p in properties)
    {
        var field = type.GetField(p);
        if (field != null)
            dDict[p] = field.GetValue(input);

        var prop = type.GetProperty(p);
        if (prop != null && prop.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0)
            dDict[p] = prop.GetValue(input, null);
    }

    return dObject;
}
```

I tried to use it like this

```
var results = from row in toSearch.AsEnumerable()
          group by row.Field<String>("Somename") into grp
          select grp;
var test = results.Select( x => DynamicProjection(x,someDic.Keys));
```

This gave me an object which i could not utilise or at least call properties out from. I would really appreciate any help in achieving what i was originally after and sorry for the long post.

**Edit**
Expected input is a datatable eg:

```
Fee | Fi | Fo | Fum
cat | ds | 2  | 93
cow | ff | 5  | 120
cat | ds | 9  | 33
cow | jk | 1  | 133
```

Group by header: Fee
Headers Received: Fo, Fum
Expected output:

```
cat | 11  | 126
cow | 6   | 253
```

Winner: Cow , so adopt a cow *Just joking lol

Comment: Can you show us input and (expected) output formats?

Comment: @HariPrasad Updated :) Thank you for taking your time to read this

Comment: So based on headers received, you want sum on those columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite familiar with `ExpandoObject` (my arguments may wrong), you could work with `Dictionary<columnname, sum>`.

I would suggest return a `Dictionary` with the headers and respective sum.

```
// ex -- Given following header
List<string> headers = new List<string>();
headers.Add("fo");
headers.Add("fum");    

DataTable dt; // Assign correct data source.
var results =dt.AsEnumerable()
        .GroupBy(g=>g.Field<string>("fee"))       
        .Select(x=> new 
                {
                    x.Key, 
                    dict = headers.ToDictionary(h=>h, h=>x.Sum(s=>s.Field<int>(h)))
                })
        .ToList();
```

This query groups on `fee`  column and calculates sum for a given header columns.

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EyWW7S)

**Output:**

```
Key=cat, column fo , Sum 11, column fum , Sum 126
Key=cow, column fo , Sum 6, column fum , Sum 253
```

Comment: Thanks ! This does not allow me to include a for loop inside the select but it provides me with an alternative. I'll wait and see if anyone is able to provide me with a for loop solution. Else I will break; and mark urs as the answer :) Cheers !

Comment: Why do you need `for loop` this is already doing the job for you. Or I missed something?

Comment: Achieving a for loop allows me to execute complex queries within one linq statement. The idea is to allow me to execute additional requirements such as if statements or for within a for loop if i need it be. Ur answer is good but I unfortunately need an answer to fit into my complexity level. Else ill break to this solution as promised earlier :)

Comment: Not completely sure, but anyways I'll up vote to get more attention to the question :-)

Comment: Thank you for your help mate :)