# Using LINQ, how can I get a joined table returned as IEnumerable<DataRow>

Tags: c#, linq

I use SQL a lot, and I'm trying to transfer the same joining logic to LINQ queries against a DataSet. The DataSet is a bunch of tables which are pulled from SQL queries further up the line.

I managed to get this join working -

```
        IEnumerable<DataRow> query =
            from a in ds.Tables["Names"].AsEnumerable()
            join b in ds.Tables["NameHasAffiliate"].AsEnumerable()
                on a.Field<int>("PK") equals b.Field<int>("fk_MainTable_PK")
            select a;
```

This doesn't compile:

```
select a.Field<int>("PK"), a.Field<string>("Name")
```

and nor does

```
select new { PK = a.Field<int>("PK"), Name = a.Field<string>("Name") }
```

It's definitely querying correctly (I see the expected amount of rows and duplicated table `a` data) but this is only returning the table `a` columns - obviously because of `select a`.

I've tried changing to `select new { a, b }` and also wrapping the query up in `()` to add an `.ToList()` at the end, but neither compiles to give me the IEnumerable version of the query for a simple converstion to table aftewards using

```
DataTable boundTable = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

How can I select ALL the columns like this?
Or rather, if I'm joining a lot of tables, how can I specify which columns from each table?

Comment: You can try `select a.propertyName, b.proprtyName` or `select new { Name = a.Name, Name1 = b.Name1 };`.

Comment: Can you post the `attributes` of both `Names` and `NameHasAffiliate` tables?

Comment: As you can see, I don't have properties defined through any sort of data object. I'm defining them in-line e.g. `a.Field<int>("PK")` and using that syntax in the `select` portion doesn't compile.

Comment: I think this link will help you out.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37849027/c-sharp-linq-dynamically-create-property-and-values-that-includes-sum-of-a-val

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I think maybe I just need to create data objects so I can call properties by name :/

Answer (score 0):

This is because returning anything other than a `DataRow` will not work in your example, since you are defining the query to be of type `IEnumerable<DataRow>`. So if you are returning a field or collection of fields, then you need to change the expected return type.

I tried the following and it works just fine.

```cs
var ds = new DataSet();

ds.Tables.Add("Names");
ds.Tables["Names"].Columns.Add("PK", typeof(Int32));
ds.Tables["Names"].Columns.Add("Name", typeof(String));
ds.Tables["Names"].Rows.Add("1", "NameValue1");

ds.Tables.Add("NameHasAffiliate");
ds.Tables["NameHasAffiliate"].Columns.Add("fk_MainTable_PK", typeof(Int32));
ds.Tables["NameHasAffiliate"].Columns.Add("AffiliateValue", typeof(String));
ds.Tables["NameHasAffiliate"].Rows.Add("1", "AffiliateValue1");



var query = 
    ds.Tables["Names"].AsEnumerable()
        .Join(
            ds.Tables["NameHasAffiliate"].AsEnumerable(), 
            n => n.Field<int>("PK"), a => a.Field<int>("fk_MainTable_PK"),
            (n, a) => new { Key = n.Field<Int32>("PK"), Name = n.Field<String>("Name")})
        .ToList();
```